# How can I reorder recyclerview from firebase permanently?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a firebase project. I used Itemtouchhelper to drag and reorder the recyclerview from firebase database but it resets to what it was if I enter another activity and comeback or restart the app. Is there a way to make the change to recyclerview order permanent?

---

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN | ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END, 0) {
@Override
public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
    int fromPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
    int toPosition = target.getAdapterPosition();

    Collections.swap(List, fromPosition, toPosition);

    adapter.notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

}};
```

---

```
private void loadList() {
List = new ArrayList<>();
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("List");
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        List.clear();
        for(DataSnapshot ss: snapshot.getChildren()){
            if(ss.child("moreList").child(ID).exists()){
                ListModel model = ss.getValue(ListModel.class);
                List.add(model);
            }
        }
        adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), List);
        RecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback);
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(RecyclerView);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

}

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: You can add a field to your database like "iOrder" and when you reorder your items, you change the value of iOrder by items position on your RecyclerView! every time you get your data from server, you order your items by iOrder field :)